# Setting the host and domain name in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci

Trying to setup testing for micro service with Gitlab-CI, I run into the problem that my MySQL users use a host and domain name to see if they are authorized to connect.

Mysq>user (table)

```
 _____________________.______
|        Host         | User | 
 —————————————————————.——————
| hostname.domain.com | jdoe |
```

However I can't find how I set the hostname and domain name of the container that runs the main `script:` in my *.gitlab-ci.yml*.

Isn't there some `variable:` I can set to tell the container its eqivelant of `container-name:` and `network` in *Docker-composer.yml* that I can set in the *.gitlab-ci.yml*?

My *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```yaml
Product-API:
  image: serversideup/php:8.2-fpm-nginx

  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.33-debian
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sed -i -e "/^skip-name-resolve/d" /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld']
  
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
    #FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

    #mysql variables
    MYSQL_DATABASE: product_db
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: [nice password]
    MYSQL_USER: jdoe
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: [nice password]
    
   ... micro services variables

  before_script:
    ...download, unpack and load the product database
    ...install micro service
    
  script:
    #######################################################
    # With this line all works fine, should work without  #
    #######################################################
    - mysql -uroot -p[nice password] --host=mysql mysql -e "RENAME USER 'jdoe'@'hostname.domain.com' TO 'jdoe'@'%';"

    - mysql -ujdoe -p[nice password] --host=mysql product_db -e 'select 1;'
```

The error given if I don't allow the user: *jdoe* to connect from any host is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'jdoe'@'172.17.0.4' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select 1)

So the IP should be *hostname.domain.com*

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, particularly `the problem that my MySQL users use a host and domain name to see if they are authorized to connect` I don't understand what you mean by this (what is the authorization component? The microservice? Why not create a db user for testing?) or how it presents a problem; why are your user workflows relevant here? --  Anyhow. Do you want to control the hostname of your mysql server or something else?

Comment: Hmm, that is very hard to say. If I read it your answers are there. To clarify the sentence you quote I added the mysql user table.

Comment: I want the docker container that the .gitlab-ci users to load my micro service to have the right hostname and domain  to connect to the mysql service that it starts that has that user table. Hope it is clearer this way

Comment: What is _connecting to_ your job container such that it needs a particular hostname? The short answer is: no, you can't control the hostname of your job container. Although `localhost` works and, in principle, you can create DNS/hosts aliases for this on self-managed runners or maybe as part of your job. But it doesn't make any sense to me why you'd have to do this. `have the right hostname and domain to connect to the mysql service` this is confusing to me because mysql doesn't know or care about the connecting client's hostname. Clients don't even need to have a hostname at all...

Comment: In other words, to connect to mysql, only the client needs to know the hostname of the mysql server. mysql doesn't need to initiate a connection to your job container because the client always initiates the connection... You **can** control the hostname of the mysql server used to connect to it. There are some other job-to-service networking solutions available, but it's hard for me to say whether any of them apply to your situation, mainly because it's not clear to me why you have this requirement for the host/DNS name of the job container.

Comment: Mysql does a nslookup on the hostname..domain.com and then does a lookup on the IP it gets to see if it returns the same info. Only if they both match will the user@hostname.domain.com pass authentication.

Comment: Because of this the dns records need to be right within the environment where gitlab runs the test. In docker-compose.yml you would setup a network and give the container a hostname and connect it to the network. I'm looking for something similar here.

Comment: If it doesn't exist I read some answers to other problems where people have a docker-compose.yml started my the .gitlab-ci.yml I guess that is something to explore. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up. I didn't realize that was configured in your my.cnf. I would recommend just not configuring the mysql service in the job to require this for the purposes of testing your app -- unless your objective is to test that configuration specifically. You might be able to use the [Network Per Build](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job) setting for this to network containers started in your job (e.g., `docker run --alias hostname.foo my-microservice`) and the `services:` and microservice container would be networked.

Comment: @sytech if you write your solution up as an answer others can see it too and I can accept it.

Comment: created a feature request for this functionality, lets see it it brings anything. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/419904